# Rails links preventing loading of external JS widget

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails

I am trying to debug an issue where our booking system doesn't load (it is an external widget loaded via javascript), sometimes.

I am able to replicate the issue buy opening the /bookings link, then clicking the bookings link again.

Once I click it again, the widget vanishes, then never reloads.  A page refresh fixes this.

Is there a way to fix this issue?  Im guessing it has something to do with how Rails loads routes.

Thanks!

Comment: im asking if rails does something to prevent JS from running with its routes...what is there to guess?

Comment: mostly turbolinks complain. also We dnt see your code to say This is the issue !!

Comment: yes it was turbolinks...didn't even realize i still had it in gemfile.

Comment: haha, nice you got it!